# How to use JPA 2.1 @NamedStoredProcedureQueries with void return parameters?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Given the following annotated named stored procedure query:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "procedureName",
        procedureName = "stored_procedure"
    )
})
```

Then executing with:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("procedureName");
query.executeUpdate();
```

The stored_procedure returns postgres `void`.

Results in an exception: `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111`
.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by using some crutch code.

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "VOID_MAPPING",
    classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = VoidClass.class, columns = {})
    }
)
```

Adding the resultSetMappings to the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`.

```
 resultSetMappings = {
        "VOID_MAPPING"
 }
```

VoidClass is simply an empty class.

```
public class VoidClass {}
```

But, I'm hoping for a better solution.